# How to make text barely visible on any background color?

Tags: css

If the background is white, the text color should be a darker shade of white. If the background is black, the text color should be a lighter shade of black. Etc.

I'm looking for a solution that I can apply to a div or span tag, e.g.

```
<div style="background-color: unknown_beforehand">
  <div class=what_goes_here? style=what_goes_here?>barely visible text</div>
...
```

Edit: I should note that the background color is unknown because it changes depending on the light/dark mode of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  The recommendation below can and will fail for colors near the middle of the spectrum (eg, `#808080`), and after quite a bit of googling, I haven't found a good alternative.  I'll leave this answer here since it may still help with some use cases, but it's not a catch-all solution, and hopefully someone else can come along with a better way to do this.

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, but one way is to use `mix-blend-mode`:

```css
.background{
  background-color: blue;
}

.background2{
  background-color: black;
}

.background3{
  background-color: white;
}

.background4{
  background-color: #808080;
}

.text{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>

<div class="background2">
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>

<div class="background3">
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>

<div class="background4">
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Can you explain how it works? Why is opacity needed?

Comment: `mix-blend-mode: difference` takes the absolute value of the difference of the text and background color and sets that value as the text's color.  Opacity is just to reduce the contrast/visibility of the text, since you said you wanted it "barely visible".

Comment: Unfortunately, I am mistaken in my recommendation - the `mix-blend-mode: difference` will fail for colors near the middle of the color spectrum (eg, `#808080`).  I will edit my answer to point this out.  After doing some googling though, I have yet to find a good way to accomplish what you're looking for.  If I think of one, I will come update this, otherwise, hopefully someone else knows the solution.